# what to use for files that reach 4TB in size?

Tags: sql-server, remote-blob-storage

We have got a customer which has 4TB of files, but we are not sure yet what kind of files they are. Now the question rises, what is the best way to store these files? Is it best to store them in SQL Server or to use RBLOB?

Can someone help me on this question?

Comment: what are the avg size of files and what is type of files? in how many site collections these files are?

Comment: Remote blob it, way too much data to store into sql server imo

Comment: We don't know yet what is the avg size of files at this moment. We need to scan them. As a start there will be 50 site collections and all these files will be spread around these site collections